# Android code to send SMS with no errors but still not sending

Tags: android, geolocation, sms, smsmanager

Here the address stores current location of the device, which works. I get a toast that says SMS Sent but no sms is actually sent from the device. If the same code is used before finding the location, it works perfectly.

```
public void sendSMS()
{
String phoneNo = "+918110020302";
String message="Our Customer "+" has booked Cab no "+" using our application CabBooking and is cureently at location: "+address;
 try {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
    q.setText(message +phoneNo);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } 

 catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}

Comment: Your message looks like it will exceed the character limit for a single-part message, in which case, you'll need to use the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen it yet, here is a working example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

It may depend on your network. If you are running this inside Android Studio's emulator, it may not work because it does not actually have cell service from within the emulator. You may need to be connected to a different network, or your cellular network.